# How many birds do I have to catch?

Tags: probability

I have the following problem with which I cannot solve. I have a very large population of birds e.g. 10 000. There are only 8 species of birds in this population. The size of each species is the same.

I would like to calculate how many birds I have to catch, to be sure in 80% that I caught one bird of each species.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you friend (I am a beginner) but this reminds me of the coupon collector problem. In Sheldon Ross Chapter 4 example 1e (A First Course in Probability) he has a solution but it's not a "nice" pmf, the solution requires some recursive calculations.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you solve the problem for 2 species?

Comment: Looks similar, I'll try to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment by @HJ_beginner, this is the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), with species of birds instead of coupons.

*A First Course in Probability, Seventh Edition* by Sheldon Ross gives the following solution to the Coupon Collector's Problem in Example 1e, section 4.1.  Let's say there are $N$ types of coupons, and let $T$ be the number of the first draw in which you have a complete set of all $N$ coupons.  Then
$$P(T>n) = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \binom{N}{i} \left( \frac{N-i}{N} \right)^n (-1)^{i+1}$$ for $n>0$.

In your case, we have $N=8$ and we want the least $n$ such that $P(T > n) < 0.2$.  By computation, the least such $n$ is $n=28$, with $P(T > 28) = 0.181464$.

Comment: Well explained. I found and computed the case yesterday getting the same results but I think that according to the cited book the solution of the problem should constitute a computation of P(T=n)? Since P(T=n)= P(T>n-1) - P(T>n) the result (0,024) drives me crazy. T is "the number of coupons that need to be collected until one obtains a complete set of at least one of each type". I suppose that n=sum of i, or?

Comment: The probability that you will have a complete set of species by bird 28 is about 0.818.  $P(T=n)$ gives the probability that you first get a complete set on turn $n$, not before or after.  I don't think that is the question you are asking.

Comment: Thank you awkward. If "T" is the number of birds that have to be caught until one obtain a complete set of at least one bird of each species, and "n" is the number of all trials (number of catches, where I catch one bird at a time), then the answer on the raised question should be: when T=n?

Comment: T is the number of birds you have caught when you first have a complete set of 8 species.  But I don't think are asking for $P(T=n)$.  You asked how many birds you have to catch to have an 80% chance of having all 8 species.  So you want $P(T \le n) > 0.8$, or equivalently, $P(T > n) < 0.2$.

Comment: got it. You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the population has $b$ birds divided equally between $s$ species then I think the probability that you have caught $k$ species after catching $n$ birds satisfies

$$P_{n+1,k}=P_{n,k-1}\frac{b(s-k+1)}{(b-n)s} +P_{n,k}\frac{bk - ns}{(b-n)s}$$

starting with $P_{0,0}=1$ and $P(0,k)=0$ for $k \gt 0$

It seems that with $b=10000$ and $s=8$, you have $P_{27,8} \approx 0.795$ and $P_{28,8} \approx 0.819$ making the answer $28$

Comment: How to calculate Pn,k-1 and Pn,k?

My approach leads me to get different values, but it is... a bit cruder. Let me please introduce them.

What is the probability that I catch one, not having species in a first trial: 100%
What is the probability that I catch one new species when I couth already one: 7/8=87,5%
…

I want to confident in 80% of the results, so I multiply the probability by the confidence level getting:
100% * 80% = 0,8 (that is the number of birds catught with 0,8 probability)
87,5% * 80% = 0,9
…

Finally  sum of all the values comes to 17,8 (birds)

Comment: It is a recursion, so you calculate $P_n,k$ from $P_{n-1,k-1}$ and $P_{n-1,k}$ and so on. If you are sampling with replacement or have $b$ infinite, then I suspect this becomes $P_{n+1,k}=P_{n,k-1}\frac{(s-k+1)}{s} +P_{n,k}\frac{k}{s}$ which could give you something like $P_{n,k}=\frac{n! \,S(n,k)}{(n-k)!\, n^k}$ where $S(n,k)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  But I would still think the answer could be $28$

Comment: In your calculation, the probability of finding a new species should go down as you find more species: hence that $\frac{(s-k+1)}{s}$ term rather than your calculation effectively involving $\frac{(s-1)}{s}$

Comment: Thank you but I cannot still get your computation results. I'd like to express my gratitude for your work accepting your answer as it was the first right one, but unfortunately, two answers cannot be marked...